# longtable, siunitx, multirow, multicolumn, textsuperscript combination problem

Tags: longtable, siunitx, multirow, multicolumn, superscripts

I have the table below with, `\multirow`, `\multicolumn` and `\textsuperscript` calls. I would like to have all entries centered, and the numerical entries additionally "scientifically" aligned right (as done by the `siunitx` package). For the time being I use `\rlap`, but that only aligns the text superscripts, not the numerical entries. Ideally, I should use something like the `siunitx` package, and in principle it should automatically align the textsuperscripts, but I am having trouble combining the `siunitx` package with my current code. Can anyone help?

```
\begin{center}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tiny}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{...}\label{tab:1}\\
\hline
Text & Text & $X$\\
     &      & $\mathrm{\left[\%\right]}$\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{l}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
\hline
Text & Text & $X$\\
     &      & $\mathrm{\left[\%\right]}$\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{r}%
{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}%
{\shortstack[l]{\textsuperscript{a}Method 1\\
\textsuperscript{b}Remark}}
\endlastfoot

Text & Text & 70.5\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 8.8\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 78.1\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 7.0\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 76.5\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 92.5\rlap{\textsuperscript{a,b}}\\
Text & \multirow{2}{*}{text} & \multirow{2}{*}{8.71\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}}\\
Text &      &\\

Text & Text & 79.2\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 69.0\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 65.2\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 77.7\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     & Text & 69.7\rlap{\textsuperscript{a,b}}\\
     & Text & 67.6\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}\\
     &      &\\
\cdashline{1-3}
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\textbf{Mean}} & 76.35\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{(SD)}          & (7.82)\\

\end{longtable}

\end{tiny}
\end{center}
```

Here the shortened MWE combining `\multirow` with `\tablenum`, to achieve the same alignment, but with larger space between the two rows than with `\makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}


\begin{longtable}{ccc}

\caption{...}\label{tab:1}\\

\hline
Text & Text & $X$\\
     &      & [\%]\\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
\hline
Text & Text &  $X$\\
     &      &  [\%]\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{r}{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}%
{\shortstack[l]{\textsuperscript{a}Method 1\\
\textsuperscript{b}Remark 1}}
\endlastfoot

\multirow{ 1}{*}{Ttext} & \multirow{ 1}{*}{Ttext} & \multirow{ 1}{*}{\tablenum[table-format = 2.1]{70.5}\rlap{\textsuperscript{a,b}}}\\
Ttext & \multirow{ 2}{*}{Ttext} & \multirow{ 2}{*}{\tablenum[table-format = 2.1]{8.7}\rlap{\textsuperscript{a}}}\\
Ttext & &\\
\cdashline{1-3}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Mean}} &  \multirow{ 1}{*}{\tablenum[table-format = 2.1]{76.3}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(SD)}          &  \multirow{ 1}{*}{\tablenum[table-format = 2.1,input-symbols=()]{(7.8)}}\\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site, you are much much more likely to get help if you post a full minimal example instead of sniplets. Then others can easily copy and work with your code. Some people might not know where `\shortstack` comes from. Also why are you using left/right like that? Not needed at all.

Comment: Thanks daleif! I'll upload the full MWE ASAP. As for the \left[...\right] it's just because I have other tables which need that and I streamlined them.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: That would be great Phelype!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}
     \item[a] Method 1
     \item[b] Remark
  \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{ccS[table-format=2.2,input-symbols=()]}
    \caption{...}\label{tab:1}\\
  \toprule
  Text & Text & $X$\\
       &      & [\%]\\
  \midrule
\endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\tablename\ \thetable\ (\emph{continued from previous page})} \\
  \hline
  Text & Text &  $X$\\
       &      &  [\%]\\
  \midrule
\endhead
  \hline 
  \multicolumn{3}{r}{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot
  \hline
  \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

Text & Text & 70.5\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 8.8\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 78.1\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 7.0\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 76.5\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 92.5\tnote{a,b}\\
\makecell{Text \\Text} & text & 8.71\tnote{a}\\

Text & Text & 79.2\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 69.0\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 65.2\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 77.7\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 69.7\tnote{a}\\
     & Text & 67.6\tnote{a}\\

\cdashline{1-3}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Mean}} & 76.35\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(SD)}          & (7.82)\\

\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

I have used `siunitx`'s `S` column with an appropriate `table-format` option in order to align the numbers with respect to the decimal separator.

For the notes, I have used the `threeparttablex` package and its `ThreePartTable` and `TableNotes` environments, as well as the `\tnote` command.

Additionally, I have replaced the `\hline`s by rules from the `booktabs` package.

I have also replaced the `\multirow` commands by a `makecell` command in the first column in order to achieve a similar layout without destroying the alignment in this particular row.

Lastly, I have removed the `center` environment as `longtable`s are centered by default. From the `longtable` documentation:

> The optional argument of `longtable` controls the horizontal alignment
>   of the table. The possible options are `[c]` , `[r]` and `[l]` , for
>   centring, right and left adjustment, respectively.  Normally centring
>   is the default,[...]

Comment: Thanks a lot leandriis! Looks great. Ideally, I would prefer to use \multirow and \textsuperscript to stay in line with the code I use for other tables for which I don't really need the siunitx package. Is it possible to elegantly achieve that at all or is it too complex?

Comment: You can also achieve the same alignment without the `threeparttable` environment and the `tnote` commands. However, I don't think it is easily possible to use `\multirow` as its contents can't be interpreted as numbers by `siunitx`. Using `{}` around the command will successfully compile, but the alignment is centered, not with respect to the decimal separator.

Comment: I can live with \makecell, but just in case I want more space between the two lines therein by using \multirow, it is possible (see shortened MWE I just added). Thanks again!